# How can I hide a control so that it no longer takes up space in WPF?

Tags: wpf, layout, visibility

I have a DataTemplate that I am using for a cell in a gridview. I would like to switch between the progress bar and the text/link block. Is there a way to hide an element so that it is removed from the flow and takes up no space while it is hidden (like "display:none" in CSS)? Is there a better way to approach this?

DataTemplate looks like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
    <StackPanel Height="40">
        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility}">
            <Hyperlink Click="btn_Authorise">
                <InlineUIContainer>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Button}" />
                </InlineUIContainer>
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}"
                     Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility}"
                     Height="15"
                     Width="150"
                     Background="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     BorderBrush="#FF8D8D8D"
                     Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarStyle1}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Visibility.Collapsed` is probably what you need (as opposed to `Visibility.Hidden` which still makes the control take part in layout calculations)

Also see the [`Visibility` enumeration reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590101.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

Visibility is an enumeration, Visible, Hidden, and Collapsed.
Hidden is just non-visible, whereas Collapsed means it takes no space also